# ng-repeat filtrar por fecha

Tags: angularjs, filtro, ng-repeat

Tengo un problema al filtrar por la fecha, dado que la que me devuelve la API está en formato AAAA-mm-dd (la cambio a formato dd-mm-AAAA con un filtro)

Pero claro, en el momento de buscar (tengo buscadores por columna) o la buscas en formato inglés o no devuelve resultados.

¿Habría alguna manera de en el filter que se hace en el ng-repeat, darle el formato correcto?

```
ng-repeat="repeat in repeatsFound= (repeats| filter: { FechaVto: search_FechaVto }) | orderBy: query.order | limitTo: query.limit : (query.page -1) * query.limit"
```

Comment: ¿Porqué realizas el cambio? Como lo devuelve la API está en formato ISO. Trata de apegarte al formato, como buena práctica. Dices: ***en el momento de buscar (tengo buscadores por columna) o la buscas en formato inglés o no devuelve resultados***. ¿Cuál es el **formato inglés**? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que recibes de la API y cómo deseas enviarlo a la vista? Saludos

Comment: Me referia a yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Eso es el formato que bota tu API. Pero debes agregar qué vas a hacer con dicho dato. Mencionas que vas a realizar una búsqueda por columnas ¿qué columnas y qué búsqueda? Por tu código entiendo que `repeatsFound` es lo que te devuelve la API, por lo tanto imagino que allí hay una `columna` con campo de fecha. Deseas filtrar por dicha columna, pero hasta allí entiendo. Hablas que aplicas un filtro diciendo: ***la cambio a formato dd-mm-AAAA con un filtro***, ¿dónde la cambias? Imagino que el cambio ocurre en este método: `search_FechaVto`. Trata de ser mas claro para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Estás en el camino correcto, el filtro lo aplico en la vista, para mostrar la fecha en el formato correcto. Lo que necesito es saber como puedo cambiar ese formato en el filtro (lo que pongo arriba filter : {}) para que lo tome en ese mismo formato, si no buscas y ves la fecha como dd-mm-aaaa y por detrás el formato es aaaa-mm-dd

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien tu problema.

Pero si el problema es el formato de la fecha podrías cambiar su formato utilizando moment,
así mas o menos.

```
 $scope.repeatsFound = $scope.repeatsFound.map(function(x){
     x.FechaVto = moment(x.FechaVto, 'AQUIFORMATOENTRANTE').format('AQUIFORMATOSALIENTE')
     return x;
 })
```